# System.Media.SoundPlayer only plays through one speaker

Tags: c#, soundplayer

I have a sound I am playing through System.Media.SoundPlayer in C#. When I play it within visual studio it plays fine through both speakers. However, when I play it using System.Media.SoundPlayer, it only plays through the left speaker. I am using the code:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer snd = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Resource1.Radio);
snd.PlayLooping();
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are your sure `Resource1.Radio` is in stereo?

Comment: Yeah, I viewed it in audacity and it is stereo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could fix it this way:

- stop windows audio service (command line: `net stop AudioSrv`)
- delete this registry folder: HKLU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore
- start windows audio service (command line: `net start AudioSrv`)

This clears any stored process-specific channel-wise volume settings, that may have been modified before (in my case this had happened through calling the `waveOutSetVolume()` API function).